# Is this Sakura's variable suit?

Tags: hundred

Sakura is a slayer not affiliated to Little Garden. So she does not have a variable suit like Hayato and the others.

But she uses a very peculiar (fanservice-wise) type of suit when she uses her Hundred on live shows:

[image]

Is this a variable suit?

Comment: Maybe not, I think, because she doesn't have the collar-like thing around her neck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is her variable suit.

[image: Sakura's variable suit]

(Source: [Anime's official site](http://hundred-anime.jp/character/); ヴァリアブルスーツ = variable suit)